# Change default category when I publish a post

Tags: posts, categories

I am using a paid curation software for my Wordpress site.  It works well but every time I post content it defaults to a standard category rather than the one I want.  Is there anyway to write code to, upon posting a new post "if category = standard, change to XXXX"?

Comment: You'd need to share code for us to be able to help, and since it's paid software you probably can't do that. Have you tried contacting the software maker's support team?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. They just don't support it and they will not provide code.  I was hoping to add code that would trigger on Publish/Submit to simply change the category.

Answer (score 2):

You can change default post category in WP Options.

Go to : **`Settings` `->` `Writing`**

choose your **`Default Post Category`** and hit save.

[image]